# Performance `comlink`, `workercom`, `@fcanvas/communicate`

Tags: javascript, typescript, performance, web-worker, comlink

I was looking for an easier way to work with `WebWorker` i found 3 npm packages that worked for my case:

- comlink: https://www.npmjs.com/package/comlink
- workercom: https://www.npmjs.com/package/workercom
- @fcanvas/communicate: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fcanvas/communicate

I am wondering the performance between these packages because i need to exchange hundreds of data (`text` or `ArrayBuffer`) per second between main thread and webworker so i need these communication quite fast.

Please help me!

Note: I read the document of `@fcanvas/communicate` and I decided to use more `MessageChannel` like this
worker.ts

```
import { listen } from "@fcanvas/communicate"

listen(self, "send port", (port: MessagePort) => {
  port.start()
  listen(port, "sort_db", () => {
    // ...
  })
  // ...
})
```

main.ts

```
import Worker from "./worker.ts?worker"
import { put } from "@fcanvas/communicate"

function createWorker() {
  const { port1, port2 } = new MessageChannel()

  const worker = new Worker()

  await put(worker, "send port", port2)
  port1.start()

  // put
}
```

I expected a fast and easy method for worker and thread communication